# unfortunately, Groceries has stopped

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am trying to start sample-Groceries from here http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-1 on android emulator and get the following message "unfortunately, Groceries has stoped"

Here is the debug messages from console

```
I/DEBUG   ( 1142):     #12 pc 005c13b1  /data/app/org.nativescript.groceries-1/lib/x86/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::RegExpImpl::CompileIrregexp(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSRegExp>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, bool)+673)
I/DEBUG   ( 1142):     #13 pc 005c1605  /data/app/org.nativescript.groceries-1/lib/x86/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::RegExpImpl::IrregexpPrepare(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSRegExp>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>)+165)
I/DEBUG   ( 1142):     #14 pc 005c1b23  /data/app/org.nativescript.groceries-1/lib/x86/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::RegExpImpl::IrregexpExec(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSRegExp>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSArray>)+51)
I/DEBUG   ( 1142):     #15 pc 005c1cd0  /data/app/org.nativescript.groceries-1/lib/x86/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::RegExpImpl::Exec(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSRegExp>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSArray>)+144)
I/DEBUG   ( 1142):     #12 pc 005c13b1  /data/app/org.nativescript.groceries-1/lib/x86/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::RegExpImpl::CompileIrregexp(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSRegExp>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, bool)+673)
I/DEBUG   ( 1142):     #13 pc 005c1605  /data/app/org.nativescript.groceries-1/lib/x86/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::RegExpImpl::IrregexpPrepare(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSRegExp>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>)+165)
I/DEBUG   ( 1142):     #14 pc 005c1b23  /data/app/org.nativescript.groceries-1/lib/x86/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::RegExpImpl::IrregexpExec(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSRegExp>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSArray>)+51)
I/DEBUG   ( 1142):     #15 pc 005c1cd0  /data/app/org.nativescript.groceries-1/lib/x86/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::RegExpImpl::Exec(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSRegExp>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSArray>)+144)
I/DEBUG   ( 1142):     #12 pc 005c13b1  /data/app/org.nativescript.groceries-1/lib/x86/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::RegExpImpl::CompileIrregexp(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSRegExp>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, bool)+673)
I/DEBUG   ( 1142):     #13 pc 005c1605  /data/app/org.nativescript.groceries-1/lib/x86/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::RegExpImpl::IrregexpPrepare(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSRegExp>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>)+165)
I/DEBUG   ( 1142):     #14 pc 005c1b23  /data/app/org.nativescript.groceries-1/lib/x86/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::RegExpImpl::IrregexpExec(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSRegExp>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSArray>)+51)
I/DEBUG   ( 1142):     #15 pc 005c1cd0  /data/app/org.nativescript.groceries-1/lib/x86/libNativeScript.so (v8::internal::RegExpImpl::Exec(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSRegExp>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSArray>)+144)
```

I tried to use Genymotion and native android emulator

Ubuntu 16.04 node.js 4.5.0 
tns --version 2.2.1

Comment: What was you steps to reproduce and system info? i.e. git clone, cd xyz, tns install, tns run android

Comment: What branch of groceries are you using? Does `tns doctor` report issues? again, what is your system and version of nativescript?

Comment: nativescript should be installed globally (as a side note)

Comment: I`ve updated nativescript as root to the lates version before start project.

Comment: OK, I would try a clean start and do the same but use `tns install` rather than npm, and also use Genymotion and use `tns run android` without the emulator flag.

Comment: I`ve tried on Genymotion before use AVD with the same result.

Comment: I reprodused all steps from documentation step by step (except npm install instead of tns install)

Comment: Just have got the same result on Geanymotion after tns install

Comment: OK, how about `tns livesync android --watch` instead of `tns run android` ?

Comment: The same. I`ve tried to debug on Android 5.0 and Android 6.0 with no luck

Comment: OK, do you have any more info in your terminal?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw/r1h1dZk0

Comment: have you been able to build and run other projects? e.g. one of the start branches from groceries?

Comment: I tried to build and deploy an ampty project after tns create my-app-name --ng with no luck
http://pastebin.com/raw/edqzXR5R

Comment: Have you met all the linux [requirements](https://docs.nativescript.org/start/ns-setup-linux) in your setup?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04 amd64 and I get the following error when I trying to install 32 libs
can`t find package lib32bz2-1.0

Comment: I1ve just used the following command to install nesessary packages 
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get install libz1:i386 libncurses5:i386 libbz2-1.0:i386 libstdc++6:i386

Comment: got the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reviewed the given scenario, however I was unable to reproduce such a problem with the getting started project and new created projects. Could you follow the below attached steps to verify whether this helps.

1. `tns create sampleProject --ng`
2. manually start android emulator
3. `tns prepare android`
4. run `tns run android`

Comment: I`ll try the same on Ubuntu 14

Comment: I will test this issue  again on Ubuntu and will write you back soon

Comment: I think that similar issue has been reported in GitHub - https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/402#issuecomment-241353643